# How to cv2.VideoCapture to read from BytesIO or an array of images

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

Instead of reading from a location on a disk, I need `reader = cv2.VideoCapture()` to read from a video in a form of either a ByteIO stream or an array of images with fps given. Or is there any way to make reader.isOpened() to loop through the frames from an array of images I have. I cannot write anything to disk

Comment: (The linked question is about the writer, but the answer covers VideoCapture as well)

Comment: hmmm what about feeding in frames?

Comment: Why do you need a VideoCapture (which, essentially, decodes a video into image frames) when you already have the video frames?